# Create extension postgis error with docker. All libs installed

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've a problem when creating extension postgis, in postgresql and Docker. I've read many post and tutorials, but I've failed :)
I'm working on WSL :

```
# uname -a
Linux 6019b3c71dfc 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# psql -U user -d database -h db
psql (11.14 (Debian 11.14-0+deb10u1), server 10.18)
Type "help" for help.

massifs=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

So, I find the postgis.control file :

```
#  find /usr -name postgis.control
/usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/postgis.control
```

And copy it (and change permissions if needed) in the right folder : `cp  /usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/postgis.control /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension`

But the error is the same :(

I've installed all the libs required :

```
# dpkg -l | grep postgis
ii  postgis                              2.5.1+dfsg-1                 amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL
ii  postgis-doc                          2.5.1+dfsg-1                 all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- documentation
ii  postgis-gui                          2.5.1+dfsg-1                 amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- GUI programs
ii  postgresql-11-postgis-2.5            2.5.1+dfsg-1                 amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-11-postgis-2.5-scripts    2.5.1+dfsg-1                 all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 11 -- SQL scripts
```

Same error :(

My docker-compose.yaml :

```
#./dj/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    env_file:
      - ./env/django.env
    build:
         context: ./myproject
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./myproject:/opt/myproject
    ports:
      - "8050:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always

  db:
    env_file:
      - ./env/postgresql.env
    image: postgis/postgis
    #image: postgres:10-alpine
    container_name: postgres_container_myproject
    hostname: db
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data-myproject:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always

  pgadmin:
    env_file:
      - ./env/pgadmin.env
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin_container_myproject
    ports:
      - "8059:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/pgadmin/data:/var/lib/pgadmin/data
    links:
      - "db:pgsql-server"
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: none

volumes:
  pgadmin_data:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

Have you an idea please ?

Comment: How are you building your image? Can you show us your Dockerfile? Have you considered just using an [existing postgis image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [postgis/docker-postgis](https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis) for if you want to check how they are doing it the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis/blob/master/14-master/Dockerfile) is a good place

Comment: I'm not mastering Docker :). So, I if understand, I create an postgis docker image, and I link it in my docker-compose.yaml file ?, with the "db" section ?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong :), the "postgis" doskcer image replace my "db" section in docker-compose.yaml, 'cause this image has postgres AND postgis. Right ?

Comment: yup, it is a postgres container with postgis installed

Comment: I change my docker-compose.ymal but therer's an existing database. I try to drop the schema, but there's still an error :`The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 10, which is not compatible with this version 13.`. I can remove all 'cause the project is beginning. I try also unsuccessfully to the remove the folder "data"

Comment: For now, it's working. Just rename the `/var/lib/postgresql/{data}` and `docker-compose down && docker-compose up --build`. Thanks :)

Comment: the repository provides supported postgres versions, if you are in a production environment you can check available tags in https://hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/tags and install like `postgis/postgis:13-3.1-alpine`

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are connecting to the **wrong server** or have a server of a **wrong version**:

```
psql (11.14 (Debian 11.14-0+deb10u1), server 10.18)
```

reports a server version of **10** (10.18) which is definitly not installed by the package `postgresql-11-postgis-2.5` (that is for version **11**).

I assume you are connecting to a different machine/container (not *localhost*) that does not have the correct packages installed.

Comment: The results in the command line are in my docker container (run with "docker exec -it ... ..."). All the libs are installed with my Dockerfile only, not manually.

Comment: @fabrice You seem not to connect to localhost, but to a host named *db* `-h db`. Try `-h localhost` and see what changes.

Comment: The host "db" is the docker host to database. It's configured in the docker-compose.yaml file.

Comment: @fabrice Please post the `docker-compose.yaml` file in your question.

Comment: it's done. Thanks